# SearchView is null android

Tags: android, searchview

Hello I am trying to implement a SearchView just like we have in Gmail .

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

searchView object is null

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dgp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".GameSearchActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game_info" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameSearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game_search" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:value="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

menu layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.dgp.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/></menu>
```

Can anyone help to understand why is this object getting null?
Thank you!!!!

Comment: shouldn't it be `app:actionViewClass`? Are you extending `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: YEAHH great catch Blackbelt!!! that fixed :D

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Menu Layout :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

use this :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

So you need to use `app` instead of `android` in the menu item tag :

```
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Comment: @StarWind, It was the solution for the question asked above. Please provide the details of your problem.

Comment: I fixed it. My problem was I was trying to access it outside of onCreateOptionsMenu, specifically in oncreate. I wanted to take the result and add it to the search edit text. (Solution is don't and look at the API for searchview more) That said the java portion of code should also be posted so we know what you are doing and for completion of an answer. My apologies for not explaining in full the issue.

Comment: @StarWind, Everything except that one line is the same as described in the question. So there was no need to copy and paste the whole code that is already in the question.

Comment: Okay, that would have been good informations :-) You get my point. Anyways we are off topic -- how to write good answers.

Answer (score 0):

To support Search view you need to use

app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"  ----in the menu xml file

And  will have to import

android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  in the java file

please look carefully imported class have to be android.support.v7.widget.SearchView . when this two parts are not same then null pointer exception may happen.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

Comment: I used:
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
         searchView =  (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

But same error:
01-06 16:51:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(27106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 16:51:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(27106): Process: com.dgp, PID: 27106
01-06 16:51:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(27106): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference

Thank you

Comment: have you checked if the menuitem is null?  Blackbelts comment is also correct, it should be app:actionViewClass not android:actionViewClass